# Convert pd.NaT to timedelta

Tags: pandas, numpy

To test a code I am creating a simple sample by hand:

```
import pandas as pd
sample = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col1': [1],
        'col2': [pd.Timedelta(hours=8)],
        'col3': [pd.Timedelta(pd.np.nan)],
    }
)
```

The last column has have `timedelta64` type and also be `pd.NaT`

There is a way to do that?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I will use this simple case to test a code that I made. However, the code expect that all columns of `sample` to be of type `timedelta`. Since I can get `NaT` values, there is a way to convert then to `timedelta`?

Comment: What do you want to replace `NaT` values with?

Comment: I will keep then as `NaT`

Comment: `NaT` is already a `Timedelta`. What do you want then?

Comment: if you copy and paste the `sample` code in the question you will find that `'col3'` is a datetime. I just want `'col3'` to be `timedelta`.

Comment: When you put any legitimate value in `col3` , it will automatically convert to `timedelta`.